# How to filter a DataFrame to only include categories that are linked to specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV dataset that looks like this:

```
country,year,happiness
A,2008,3.72
A,2009,4.4
A,2011,3.83
B,2009,5.49
B,2010,5.27
B,2011,5.87
B,2012,5.51
C,2010,5.46
C,2011,5.32
D,2009,6.42
D,2010,6.44
D,2011,6.78
```

My goal is to filter it to **only include countries that have the years 2009 and 2010 and 2011**, and then to further filter it to **only include the years 2009 and 2010 and 2011**.

Thus, here is the desired result:

```
country,year,happiness
B,2009,5.49
B,2010,5.27
B,2011,5.87
D,2009,6.42
D,2010,6.44
D,2011,6.78
```

Notice that **countries A and C were excluded** from the output because they didn't include all three years, and the **2012 record for country B was also excluded** from the output.

This pandas code does accomplish the result:

```py
y09 = df.loc[df['year'] == 2009, 'country']
y10 = df.loc[df['year'] == 2010, 'country']
y11 = df.loc[df['year'] == 2011, 'country']

countries = set(y09) & set(y10) & set(y11)
years = [2009, 2010, 2011]

filtered = df.loc[df['country'].isin(countries) & df['year'].isin(years), :]
```

However, **I'm looking for a more elegant way to achieve the same result using pandas**, such that the solution would easily scale to a much larger range of years (say 50 years).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
years_of_interest = {2009, 2010, 2011}

(df[df['year']
 .isin(years_of_interest)]
 .groupby('country')
 .filter(lambda x: set(x['year']) == years_of_interest)
)
```

This seems to be the most performant way so far for me. On 1,000,000 records it runs in
35 ms ± 672 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` operations:

```
keep = {2009,2010,2011}

s = (df
     .groupby(df['country'])['year'].agg(set)
     .ge(keep)
    )

# does the country have all wanted years?
m1 = df['country'].isin(s[s].index)
# keep only wanted years
m2 = df['year'].isin(keep)

out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
   country  year  happiness
3        B  2009       5.49
4        B  2010       5.27
5        B  2011       5.87
9        D  2009       6.42
10       D  2010       6.44
11       D  2011       6.78
```

Intermediates:

```
   country  year  happiness     m1     m2  m1&m2
0        A  2008       3.72  False  False  False
1        A  2009       4.40  False   True  False
2        A  2011       3.83  False   True  False
3        B  2009       5.49   True   True   True
4        B  2010       5.27   True   True   True
5        B  2011       5.87   True   True   True
6        B  2012       5.51   True  False  False
7        C  2010       5.46  False   True  False
8        C  2011       5.32  False   True  False
9        D  2009       6.42   True   True   True
10       D  2010       6.44   True   True   True
11       D  2011       6.78   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 1):

first group by country, then check if countries contain all the years and finally do the filtering:

```
years = {2009, 2010, 2011}
c = df.groupby('country')['year'].apply(lambda x: set(x)>=years)
countries = c[c].index
df[(df["country"].isin(countries)) & (df["year"].isin(years))]
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter to years of interest, then use `nunique` to further filter to countries containing all years:

```
year_filter = {2009,2010,2011}

df = df[df.year.isin(year_filter)]
nunique_by_country = df.groupby("country")["year"].agg(["nunique"]).reset_index()
countries = nunique_by_country[nunique_by_country["nunique"] == len(year_filter)]["country"]
df = df[df.country.isin(countries)]
```

Output:

```
country year    happiness
3   B   2009    5.49
4   B   2010    5.27
5   B   2011    5.87
9   D   2009    6.42
10  D   2010    6.44
11  D   2011    6.78
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you unstack the columns such that the countries will be indexes of the rows and the years will be columns and then filter the countries such that the years 2009, 2010 and 2011 will be non empty and then stack the data again such that there will be a separate column for country, year and value. Then one can query the years 2009, 2010 and 2011.

Answer (score 0):

```
select_year=[2009,2010,2011]

country_list=df[df['year'].isin(select_year)].groupby(['country'])['year'].agg({'count'}).reset_index().query('count==3')['country'].values

df[(df['country'].isin(country_list))&(df['year'].isin(select_year))]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
 result=df.groupby('country').filter(lambda x: x['year'].nunique() == 3).query('year in [2009, 2010, 2011]')
```

If you have more years maybe create a variable that holds the values and uniquely counts it too.

Comment: This code doesn't actually produce the desired output.